Static files not served correctly all the time in development environment
I have a Flask Python web app and I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition for my development needs. I have set FLASK_ENV=development inside my .flaskenv file and I run the web app by right-clicking app.py in my solution list and selecting "Start without debugging".
This mostly works well. However, I notice that sometimes, checking the web browser console, there are errors loading files inside the static folder, mostly JS and images. These usually correct themselves with page reloads, but I sometimes go 5 reloads in a row before all the static files get loaded properly.
I do not see a pattern on when these happen, nor which files will have problems. I have yet to encounter this same problem for loading external JS files. I'm loading on average around 20 images and 2 JS files per page inside the static folder. I do not encounter this issue on the "live" site.
Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

Can you show us your code?
